# Overload function by type of vector in argument

Tags: c++, stl

Is it possible to overload the function by type of vector in argument? for example:

```
void f(std::vector<int> arg)
{
    ...
}

void f(std::vector<std::string> arg)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, they're different type at all.

Comment: Try it. Does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, It is . As per overloading concepts, if your parameter type is different, you can overload it and `vector<int>` and `vector<string>` are two different types.